# Python. Как "стукнуть" декоратором, то что функция должна запуститься?

Tags: python

```
message = ""

def new_message(func):
    def notif():
        func(message)
    return notif

def create():
    message = "hi"
    new_message()

@new_message
def print(message):
    print(message)

create() #hi
```

Можно ли реализовать такой код на Python? Если нет, то есть ли какие нибудь альтернативы?

Comment: что вы хотите получить в результате? сейчас ваш код подменяет функцию print, и она начинает сама себя бесконечно вызывать

Comment: Этот код вообще не компилируется для начала. А результатом я хочу получить выполнение функции, которая находится под декоратором, но при этом функция должна быть запущена запуском декоратора, а не функции под декоратором

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понял по вопросу что хотели, но думаю, если посмотрите всю поднаготную декоратора(без синтаксического сахара), то поймете, как он работает (убрал в комммент часть Вашего кода и прокинул аргументы):

```
# message = ""

def func(mes):
    print('Я функция, которую хотят стукнуть =(')
    print('И хотят, чтобы я сказзала - ', mes)


def new_message(_func_, _message_):
    def notif(arg):
        _func_(mes=arg)
    return notif(arg=_message_)

def create():
    message = "hi"
    new_message(_func_=func,
                _message_=message)

# @new_message
# def print(message__):
#     print(message__)

print = create() #hi

print
```

Comment: А для чего в аргументах функции new_message func берется в нижнее подчеркивание?

Comment: В данном случаю, я просто изменил имя переменной, чтобы Вы видели, как и куда убегают переменные. На самом деле нижнее подчеркивание используется в ООП для указания видимости переменной. Но в этом случае использую только для того, чтобы показать как и куда уходят переменные. И чтобы не использовать другие имена, типа arg1, arg2 и т.д

Comment: @АлексейБелкин В чем смысл Вашего кода? Я пойду от обратного. `func(mes)` вызывается в `new_message.<locals>.notif`, а потом `notif` сразу же вызывается. Это упрощается в `_func_(mes=_message_)`. Далее вызов `new_message(_func_=func, _message_=message)` упрощается до `func(message)`. Это сводится к тому, что Вы просто вызываете функцию `func`! И самое главное, результат функции `create()` (т.е. None) записываете в `print`, тем самым перезаписываете стандартную функцию вывода, зачем? Вы не правильно раскрыли декоратор. Я не согласен с Вашим ответом! Но @Dariuz выбрал Ваш ответ верным... Что?

Comment: @Be3y4uu_K0T, я просто сделать то, что хотел сделать Daris и показал принцип работы функций. По сути декоратор - это функция в функции, чтобы не изменять код некоторой функции. Переменными я указал что куда бежит. Код действительно никакой полезности не имеет, но главное - это показать что куда бежит. Действительно для работы декоратора можно было просто  создать 2 функции и в 1 вызвать другую, но тогда было бы не понятно как вкладывать множество функций друг в друга и как им передавать аргументы. Поэтому этот код просто показывает как прокидываются аргументы и сами функции.

Comment: @АлексейБелкин, допустим я не знаю имя функции func, можно ли как то по другому это сделать?

Comment: @Dariuz, " _ func _ " - это формальный параметр(написал с 2 пробелами, т.к. форматирование включается). Вместо можно хоть что написать, хоть "ABCDE", а вот "func" - это уже реальное имя функции и тут надо его реально указать. НО! ЧИСТО ТЕОРЕТИЧЕСКИ! Например ты не знаешь имя функции, но знаешь в какой функции она работает, тогда ты можешь задекорировать  функцию, содержащую неизвестную функцию)))

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от того, что Вы хотите сделать. Декоратор — это функция, которая позволяет обернуть другую функцию для расширения её функциональности без непосредственного изменения её кода. Декораторы достаточно полезны. Они расширяют возможности функции без редактирования её кода и являются гибким инструментом для изменения чего угодно (к примеру, декораторы часто применяются в работе с Flask Framework).

Однако в приведённом Вами кодом лично я бы не использовал декораторы (в данном случае проще без них). А вообще подробнее почитать о декораторах можно вот [тут](https://tproger.ru/translations/demystifying-decorators-in-python/).

Comment: а можете привести пример данного кода без декоратора пожалуйста?

Comment: А что Вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: в вопросе в коде примерно я попытался передать мою идею. я хочу, чтобы функция под декоратором вызывалсь при вызове декоратора, а не декоратор вызывался при функции

Comment: Так Вы же мне ранее написали, чтобы я привёл пример кода без декораторов.

Comment: Что Вы хотите получить при выполнении кода?

Comment: ну так потому что вы написали, что можете сделать этот код без декораторов

Comment: Ваш код при запуске не работает. Я не понимаю, что Вы хотите получить при выполнении кода?

Comment: Anaconda, я и создал вопрос, потому что код не работает. Если вы продумаете код, проанализировав его, вы поймете что я хочу сделать.

Comment: На данный момент Ваш код подменяет print(), а она в свою очередь начинает бесконечно сама себя вызывать. Вам нужен такой результат? Если да, то можно сделать так: while True: print("Hello!")